# jquery - Object ... has no method 'css'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't I change the CSS of this element?

```
  $("div.example ul li").mouseover(function () {
      var ul_teirs = $("div.example ul li").find('ul');
      var second_teir = ul_teirs[0];
      var third_teir = ul_teirs[1];

      second_teir.css({
         ...
      });
  });
```

error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLUListElement> has no method 'css'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you use `[]` to access an item in a jQuery array, you get the DOM element, not a jQuery object, so it doesn't have any jQuery methods.

Try `.eq()` instead:

```
var second_tier = ul_tiers.eq(0);
second_tier.css({ ... });
```

(Note that I changed the spelling of "tier" in the variable name. Sorry, I can't help myself.)

Comment: Whoops, noticed that I was incorrect here - @Dogbert had the right answer. Since this was already selected as correct, I'm updating my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
  var second_teir = ul_teirs.eq(0);
  var third_teir = ul_teirs.eq(1);
```